# Disable options in drop down using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down using rails with options of agents to work with in different provinces.

I would like to make it so that some options are not able to be selected, but rather act as subgroups for the agents.

ex.

---Ontario---
Agent 1
Agent 2
Agent 3

---Quebec----
Agent 1
Agent 2
Agent 3

I don't want the provinces (i.e., Ontario and Quebec) to be selectable but rather just a way to organize the drop down for the user.

This is my current code for the drop down:

```
  <%= f.label :agent_request, 'Mortgage Agent Request' %>:
  <div class="styled-dropdown">
    <%= f.select :agent_request, options_for_select([['Select One', ''], 'James Laird', 'Bryan Freeman', 'Ahjaz Mussa', 'Vince Anton', 'Peter Pancevic', 'Cedric Scarlett'], @application.agent_request), {}, tabindex: 14 %>
  </div>
```

Can someone please help me? I don't know much about rails at all!

thanks

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-grouped_collection_select

Comment: thanks, i'm not sure how to incorporate that into my existing code though. I really don't know anything about rails, i'm trying to fix another developers code. Can you please show me how you would put that in my code?

Answer (score 0):

In this example James Laird and Bryan Freeman would be disabled

```
  <%= f.label :agent_request, 'Mortgage Agent Request' %>:
  <div class="styled-dropdown">
    <%= f.select :agent_request, options_for_select([['Select One', ''], ['James Laird', {disabled: 'disabled'}], ['Bryan Freeman', {disabled: 'disabled'}], 'Ahjaz Mussa', 'Vince Anton', 'Peter Pancevic', 'Cedric Scarlett'], @application.agent_request), {}, tabindex: 14 %>
  </div>
```